# Rails Active Record exception: "An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jdbc, rails-activerecord

Currently using the `gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '~> 61.1'` in my Rails app. Running the app locally with a local db produces no error, while deploying and running the executable of the app in a k8 container sometimes produces an exception `ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.` The environments (my local and the k8 container) are similar, and I do not think the difference in environment is the root cause for the error. One difference between the two environments being that the deployed app makes a connection to a remote production db instead of a local one.

After reading online, it seems the db connection times out. Thus, I should catch the exception, reopen the db connection, and try [again](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/42540D4D.2000504%40hogranch.com).

1. Any other ideas on the cause of this error? I am not too sure the scope of where to investigate (my code, my docker container, the settings of the production db, etc).
2. The db connection is handled by this ruby jdbc gem. I am wondering if I just need to customize/edit this gem / upgrade this gem to handle this error.

I will add more to this post if the question needs more context.

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log say?

Comment: It says:`FATAL:  connection to client lost` and `LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe`

Comment: Then it sounds like a network problem, probably a firewall or router that closes idle connections. Use the [PostgreSQL TCP keepalive parameters](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tcp-keepalive-for-a-better-postgresql-experience/) to fight that.